# How to get enemy to follow character using angles? (atan2)

Tags: java, angles

I have an enemy and a character to control. I want to get the enemy to follow the character in a straight line. I already found the angle in which the enemy needs to travel.

```
double angle = Math.atan2(y, x) * 180 / Math.PI;
```

Now, let's say it return 73.0. What do I do with that number? And what if it's a negative angle.

BTW, I'm using dx(dynamic x) and dy(dynamic y) to control movement.

Comment: you don't really need atan2 though. Treat the difference in x and y value as vector components. Normalize them and multiply it with a "speed".

Comment: Though you do not need trigonometric functions here, the arctan yields 'the angle'. There are only a few reasons for converting to degrees; your wording suggests they don't apply. Useful calculations are generally done in radians.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need to know the angle, because the difference in X and Y already gives you the desired orientation of the enemy. The only thing that remains to be done is normalise that direction vector (if possible -- otherwise it means the player and the enemy are exactly at the same position), and multiply it by the enemy’s speed:

```
dx = player_x - enemy_x;
dy = player_y - enemy_y;
float norm = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
if (norm)
{
    dx *= (enemy.speed / norm);
    dy *= (enemy.speed / norm);
}
```

Comment: This has the major advantage of not needing to do any sines and cosines, which can take longer to perform than a relatively simple square-root.

Comment: Thanks! This worked really well and the enemy moves really smoothly.

Answer (score 4):

```
double angle = Math.atan2(y,x);  // Note: keeping angle in radians for cos & sin.
dx = enemy.speed * Math.cos( angle );
dy = enemy.speed * Math.sin( angle );
```

This will work fine with negative angles.

See also: [What are atan and atan2 used for in games?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14602/what-are-atan-and-atan2-used-for-in-games/45549#45549)

Comment: Thank you. I tried this, and it works fine while the character is still. But while the character is moving, the enemy just shakes. Any idea how to fix this?