# Center of Image whose height, width and position are known

Tags: mathematics, javascript, html-canvas

I have been struggling to find the center of an image(rectangle). I have following data with me:

```
width: w,
height: h,
position: (x,y)
```

My image is an object on canvas. I am using [KonvaJS](http://konvajs.github.io/docs/) framework. My concern is not specific to image it's with `Rect`, `Square` as well but cause images are actually rectangle or squares and I believe that solution will be common for all. What I want to do is I need to find the center of the shape so that I can perform the desired operation. eg. I want to place the connector between a circle and image. End point of the connectors should be at the center like the way I have displayed it in image. Please let me know what should I do to achieve this. I believe it will be done by `Math.atan()` and `Math.atan2()` but don't know how can I use them. I am new to this bizarre.

[image]

Comment: What about (X+w/2, y+h/2)?

Comment: Are you struggling with the maths or with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `(X,Y)` is at the top-left corner of the rectangle as you have drawn in the picture in your question, then the center is simply:

```
(X + W*0.5 , Y - H*0.5 )
```

Note that it is always a good practice to multiply by 0.5 instead of dividing by 2, since multiplications are much less computationaly expensive than divisions.

Comment: I think it should not be simply like this. What I want to achieve it something like this http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14602/what-are-atan-and-atan2-used-for-in-games so that I need not be worried about whether x and y are negative or positive.

Comment: @Hitesh Kumar Do you mean that the rectangles can be rotated?

Comment: it draggable. So it can be at any position. I am not sure your approach will work or not. Cause ideally we should subtract the half of diagonal from x and y rather than of half of width and height

Comment: @HiteshKumar It does not matter if X or Y are positive or negative, nor if the rectangle can be dragged. If the rectangle does not rotate (and if X,Y is in the top-left), then the rectangle's center will always be given by that simple formula. If the rectangle can rotate, then you will need the diagonal through some trigonometry

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for clarification. Now the only confusion is regarding to diagonal and dimension. which one should I use? and also please edit your answer I think we need to do (y+H*0.5) rather than (y- H*0.5)

Comment: _"Note that it is always a good practice to multiply by 0.5 instead of dividing by 2, since multiplications are much less computationaly expensive than divisions."_ That's premature optimization. :)

Comment: @HiteshKumar Seeing the amount of requests that you have, it's probably because _your_ question is unclear. Please edit it and improve it.

Comment: @Alexandre Vaillancourt Oh come on! That's such a simple, irresistible good practice... :)

Comment: I'm not saying you should not do it, it's just that the rationale behind it is no longer valid. It might have been true years ago, but now you'll have so many other things that will take more of the resources that these micro optimizations might not be worth the trouble :)

Comment: @HiteshKumar That's why I said "if X,Y is in the top-left" corner of the rectangle, as in your image. If that is the case, my answer is correct: you need `Y-H*0.5`. Now, if the image in your question is wrong and `X,Y` is actually at the bottom-left corner of the rectangle, then yes you will need `Y+H*0.5`.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt Just kidding! But you see, of course there are more important things. The issue is: there is no such a thing as premature optimization. There is only costly vs. not costly optimizations. The costly, difficult ones, should never be done before needed, indeed, at the risk of getting in the way of the programmer. However, other simple ones as that (or e.g. storing square root of 2 in a variable for re-use) are just so easy to do while coding, so not costly, that there just isn't a good reason why not to adopt them as good practices, IMHO. But we digress... :D

Comment: @MAnd I agree :)

Answer (score 0):

`width: w,
height: h,
position: (x,y),
centre: (x + w/2, y + h/2)`

Hope it helps.